# ruby import json data

Tags: arrays, json, ruby

How can I use parsed data from the data.rb file in the main.rb file ?

I'm trying to count the number of times the year "2017" occurs, and how many times "2014" occurs.

I want to return both counts to the method count_years which is in main.rb. How is this properly done?

**main.rb**

```js
def count_years
File.open('data.rb'))[:phone_data]
    if :phone_data."Year" == 2017
       year_2017.count #new variable year_2017
    end
    if :phone_data."Year" == 2014
       year_2014.count #new variable year_2014
    end
end
```

**data.rb**

```js
let(:phone_data) {
  JSON.parse('[
{
  "Phone": "iPhone 6",
  "Year": "2014"
},
{
  "Phone": "iPhone 7",
  "Year": "2016"

},
{
  "Car": "iPhone 8",
  "Year": "2017"
},
{
  "Car": "Galaxy S8",
  "Year": "2017"
}

]')
}
```

**main.rb**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby class methods and iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47521477/ruby-class-methods-and-iteration)

Comment: Your third account for asking the same question again? You even forgot to change "Car" to "Phone" in your last two array elements.

Answer (score 0):

The `data.rb` file is set up to be used by RSpec. Even in that context, it's a little awkward. I would move the JSON data to JSON file and then you can access it from both places. There are other options as well but I would need to know more about your application and how and where you're using this data.

#### data.json:

```
[
  {
    "Phone": "iPhone 6",
    "Year": "2014"
  },
  {
    "Phone": "iPhone 7",
    "Year": "2016"
  },
  {
    "Car": "iPhone 8",
    "Year": "2017"
  },
  {
    "Car": "Galaxy S8",
    "Year": "2017"
  }
]
```

#### data.rb:

```
require 'json'

let(:phone_data) {
  JSON.parse(File.read('data.json'))
}
```

#### main.rb:

```
require 'json'

def count_years
  JSON.parse(File.read('data.json'))
    .group_by { |h| h['Year'] }
    .map { |year, entries| [year, entries.size] }
    .to_h
end
```

The method will return a hash where the keys are the years and the values are the counts:

```
count_years # => {"2014"=>1, "2016"=>1, "2017"=>2}
```